# How to make Ajax request from a drupal page?

Tags: views, ajax

I have tried to make an Ajax request from drupal page. But output data is not correct . I have tried this

Ajax code:

```
function searchemail()
{
var email =$('#email').val();
    alert(email);
        $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "emailcheck.php",
        data: "email="+"test",
        success: function(ret){
     alert(ret);
        },
        error: function(x,e){
            alert("error occur");
        }
    })

}
```

Output Code

```
<?php

echo "test"+$_REQUEST['email'];
```

But it prints only a 0 instead of 'test'

Comment: If you're not using the Drupal API, this is just a basic JS/PHP question which can be asked on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Have look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "emailcheck.php",
  data: { email: "test" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Also check your url. Your PHP file has to be in the same folder as your js file when you use relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's ajax as jQuery is default part of Drupal (so no extra lib needed) like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

The php handling of the request has to be inside the file where the url part points to. The data you send is to be found inside $_POST variable inside PHP. if you don't know for sure which array element, just `var_dump($_POST);` and find out.

**For the JSON encoding part of the AJAX call:**

I've found this great jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/

This will generate a nice JSONstring to send in the data part of your AJAX call.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are not sending the data in json format. If it has to be sent using json format, please try some thing like 
    **data: {"some":"some"}**

Comment: i have tried json but it didnt worked

Comment: did you try "data: {email:test}"?